# Do all phony targets need to be listed with .PHONY?

Tags: linux, makefile

If I have a phony target, do I need to list it with the .PHONY tag or can I avoid doing it? If I don’t list it, will there be an error?

Comment: What is *a phony target,* other than a target listed with the `.PHONY` tag?

Comment: @beta when the target file is not a file that needs to be produced

Comment: If you don't declare it so with `.PHONY`, then Make will treat it as an ordinary target, and will not execute the rule if a file with that name exists (and is not older than any of its prerequisites). That is the only problem that will occur (apart from a possible cost to performance).

Answer (score 0):

If your target is not a file, there is no harm in not listing it in `.PHONY` as long as there is no file named like the target.

An example being the target `clean` which is often added to remove files - it does not build a file named `clean`. If you don't list `clean` in `.PHONY` and there is a file named `clean` in cwd, `clean` recipe won't run since the file `clean` is up to date.

Personally I don't bother adding non-file targets to `.PHONY`. Having a non-file target AND a file named like that target is a bigger issue if you ask me. You only need `.PHONY` when current make session cannot determine whether target is up to date, which often happens when doing recursive make.